# Arcpy: Geometry object - distanceTo method in a for loop

Tags: arcpy, geometry, cursor

I'm new to Python so sorry for this maybe trivial question.

I have 4 lines and 4 points, which belong together. I want to get the closest distance from point 4 to line 4, point 3 to line 3, ... . I want to use a SearchCursor and Geometry methods (distanceTo), no geoprocessing tool like "Near".

[image]

The code is used so far is:

```
    import arcpy

    point_feature = r"C:\Users\name\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb\Gas_points"
    line_feature = r"C:\Users\name\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb\Gas_lines"

    pointcursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(point_feature, ['SHAPE@'])
    linecursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(line_feature, ['SHAPE@'])

    for row in pointcursor:
        geometry = pointcursor[0]
        print geometry.type
        for row in linecursor:
            newgeometry = linecursor[0]
            print newgeometry.distanceTo(geometry)
```

The result i get:

point
6.47818694862
67.4681286231
66.0830276147
67.4681286231
point
point
point

Should be a logical mistake in the for loop, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reinitialise the linecursor for every point feature iteration

```
import arcpy

    point_feature = r"C:\Users\name\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb\Gas_points"
    line_feature = r"C:\Users\name\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb\Gas_lines"

    pointcursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(point_feature, ['SHAPE@'])        

    for row in pointcursor:
        geometry = pointcursor[0]
        print geometry.type
        linecursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(line_feature, ['SHAPE@'])
        mindist = 9999999
        for row in linecursor:
            newgeometry = linecursor[0]
            tmpdist = newgeometry.distanceTo(geometry)
            if tmpdist < mindist:
                mindist = tmpdist
        print mindist
```

Comment: thank you. It works, but i get the distances to all lines, the result i get is:

        point
        6.47818694862
        67.4681286231
66.0830276147
        67.4681286231
        point
        30.951053289
        5.21964710949
        31.5203478296
31.5203478296
point
26.5954440562
26.4388105082
26.5954440562
5.02949987677
point
44.846804569
44.846804569
18.5481780641
41.6929056041


I only need the shortest distances to the relevant line (point 3 to line 3, point 4 to line 4 ,...) ...therefore 6.47, 5.21, 5.02, 18.54. Any idea?

Comment: See my updated answer.  You can save the "mindist" value and closest line ID for each point feature.